# jQuery submit for two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a basic form popup that will display when the button buy now of the main product is clicked with this code: `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"`

and i have related products too in the same page with this main product with exactly the same button, and i want this pop up to be displayed also when it's clicked, and i tried to add `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"` to it too but if i push it the pop up WILL work but will add to the CART both products.

**how can i do this?**

the code looks like this:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="ajax-popup">
    <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
    <h2 id="ajax-popup-message"></h2>
    <div id="ajax-popup-content"></div> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;
        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }
        var e = null;
        // Start of our new ajax code
        if (!url) {
            url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
        }
        url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index"); // New Code
        var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
        data += '&isAjax=1';
        jQuery('#ajax_loader').show();
        try {
            jQuery.ajax( {
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data : data,
                success : function(data) {
                    jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
                    //alert(data.status + ": " + data.message);

                    jQuery('#ajax-popup-message').addClass(data.status);

                    if(jQuery('#ajax-popup')){
                        jQuery('#ajax-popup-message').html(data.message);
                    }
                    if(jQuery('#ajax-popup')){
                        jQuery('#ajax-popup-content').html(data.sidebar);
                    }
                    if(jQuery('.header .links')){
                        jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                    }

                    jQuery('#ajax-popup').bPopup();
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
        }
        // End of our new ajax code
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
</script>
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="first">
<div class="add-to-cart">
<img onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" title="Add to Cart" src="../images/add-to-cart.png">
</div></div>
//STUFF
<div class="second">
<button onclick="window.location='URL'; productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="form-button add-to-cart" type="button"></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Trevor i don't see a way how to make a fiddle, the idea is that i want if i fire the side product to not add in the cart the main one, because however the two are linked with this 'onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"' and some how i want to unbind the main product before i fire the side product, do you get my idea :( ?

Comment: @Trevor any idea :( ?

Comment: So if you fire the event for the main product then it only adds the main product and not the side product as well?  Can I see your html?

Comment: @Trevor i updated the answer with how is the structure of HTML, THANKS!!

Comment: Sorry I have to admit I don't have a very good handle on what is going on.  Or how your code works.. Do you by chance have a live webpage where I could see whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

The root of your issue is, from what I can see from your example, that you are calling the form submission function twice. It appears that the second onclick had debug code with the window.location left in it when you pasted it here, of which is, what I can only determine from your description, the popup window markup that causes an endless loop of submitting items to the cart.

Firstly you're using jQuery to make programming with Javascript easier, get rid of the onclick= DHTML events in your html and use jQuery.
then add

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.add-to-cart').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        productAddToCartForm.submit(this);
    });
});
```

Secondly there's no reason to wrap `jQuery.ajax` in a `try catch`, it has it's own error processing functionality. Unless you believe something would be wrong with jQuery's ajax function. Otherwise if you are trying to catch errors within the success method, you need to place the code inside the success method.

Think of ajax as a completely separate browser being opened up the instant it is executed.

Here's an example of what I am referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/73gpC/1/

Here's an example of an error method:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    error: function(jqXHR, text, errorThrown){
       if(errorThrown){
           alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
       }
    }
});
```

Next you have already declared the form with `var form = this.form;`, why search the DOM for it again?
`jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();`
should be `form.serialize();`

Every time you execute `jQuery('selector')`, jQuery "searches" for the element within the DOM.

While it sounds okay at first, as you begin dealing with more complex applications it is extremely slow to do things this way while the user interacts with your application.
It is much faster to use the declared variable instead since you already found it. With that said always favor ID's over class names as they are much faster to find but require valid HTML (ID's are unique and can not be reused).

From the look of it `<button onclick="window.location='URL'; productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"` is just completely broken and you are expecting it do something it simply won't because `window.location='URL'` is going to redirect the users browser to 'URL' when they click it and `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` will never execute.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CZqDL/

No alert box will be displayed on click, indicating the function never fired.

I am all for helping someone learn how to figure out an issue if I am able, but this is really beyond your experience level with Javascript or jQuery in general. 
I suggest getting a jQuery programming book or hiring a developer to program it correctly. 
Especially seeing as how VarienForm is a part of Magento, which should be listed in your tags, which is an eCommerce application.

If you're just learning I suggest reaching out on the jQuery or Magento forums on how to use the applications or possibly for training.
Otherwise you will lose customers, get incorrect orders, or possibly be sued or arrested (depending on if you are processing credit cards) should your form mess up due to poor programming practices.
There are many websites where you can hire a freelancer to do just what you need for very low costs and avoid the hassles.